# Where is the Kurento-client.js API documentation?

Tags: kurento

I have scanned the 380-pages "Kurento Documentation, Release 6.4.0" as well as Github. I could not find **Kurento-client.js** API documentation. The examples/tutorial do explain the API, through examples, but I could not find one document which lists the API in its entirety, as is usually expected as standard documentation with any API.

If there is one, please point me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most detailed, official location I have found to date:

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/client-jsdoc/index.html